# MULTIPLE RADIO BUTTON

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this in my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE)
    </div>
</div>
```

**in my database, it is represented as integer**

The question is

1. How do I create 3 radio buttons as a group. 1=>Local, 2=>foreign, 3=>others
2. and when any of these is clicked, it will save the integer, 1 or 2 or 3 as the case may be into the database.
3. When I want to retrieve it, it will display the strings, that is Local, foreign or others, as the case may be.

Comment: `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE, 1, new { id = "" })` and ditto for `2` and `3`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please am new to it. How do I add 2, and 3. Also note that they all belong to OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE. There something I forgot, If I click 1=>Local, it will display a message, you have chosen Local, If 2=>foreign, you have chosen Foreign. etc

Comment: `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE, 2, new { id = "" })` (and ditto for 3)

Comment: in order to display a message - you need to write a javascript, and call it on click of each radio button. You need to supply "onclick" attribute in each radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to this I'll explain in a few small steps.

### ViewModel:

Whatever data I am getting, before returning the entity from the DB to the View, I always create a ViewModel. This way I can build up and control everything I want to be passed on to the View, no more no less.

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public List<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
    public int SelectedChoice { get; set; }
}

public class Choice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

### View:

The View is the interface shown to the user and it can display anything that is in the ViewModel I passed along.

```
<div>
@foreach (var c in Model.Choices)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedChoice, c.Id) @c.Display
}
</div>
```

### Controller:

Here's where the work is done. You could have more layers but for this example the code is simple enough:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new HomeViewModel {Choices = GetChoices()};
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel vm)
{
    var selected = vm.SelectedChoice;
    return Json(new {Success = true});
}

private static List<Choice> GetChoices()
{
    return new List<Choice>
    {
        new Choice {Id = 1, Display = "Local"},
        new Choice {Id = 2, Display = "Foreign"},
        new Choice {Id = 3, Display = "Others"}
    };
}
```

**Getting the selected value with a button:**

Change the code of the view to following:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
    {
        foreach (var c in Model.Choices)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedChoice, c.Id) @c.Display
        }
        <button id="postButton">OK</button>
    }
</div>
```

Add following JavaScript code to the View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#postButton").click(function() {
        var request = $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
          data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
          cache: false,
          type: "POST"
        });

        request.error(function (error) {
            alert(error);
        });
      });
  });
</script>
```

To get the selected value when a selection changes, use the following JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(":radio[name=SelectedChoice]").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the problem is solved. But how do I display message when each button is clicked